# How to draw a Polyline Point for Point

Tags: c#, uwp

Got a annoying Problem. How can i draw a "timed" Polyline?

I have a bunch of Points that will draw me a nice polyline. The challenge is that i want to draw it "slowly", with a selectable delay before the next point gets added. I'm sure you guys know how to make it, but I couldn't find anything on google or here.

My code:

```
    private void Button_Fire_P1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        double InputAngle = Slider_Angle_P1.Value;
        double InputSpeed = Slider_Speed_P1.Value;

        List<Point> P1points = new List<Point>();

        P1points = Projectile_Path_to_Right(1.0, 728.0, InputAngle, InputSpeed);
        int delay = Convert.ToInt32(InputSpeed);

        for (int i = 0; i < P1points.Count; i++)
        {
            Poly1.Points.Add(P1points[i]);
        }

        P1points.Clear();
    }
```

Edit: as you can see, my Polyline is created in the XAML, within a canvas.

```
  <Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="Gray">
        <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Width="1024" Height="728">
            <Rectangle x:Name="BarrellP1" Height="2" Width="40" Canvas.Top="728" Canvas.Left="0" Fill="Red"/>
            <Rectangle x:Name="BarrellP2" Height="2" Width="40" Canvas.Top="728" Canvas.Left="1020" Fill="Orange"/>
            <Polyline x:Name="Frame" Stroke="Black"/>
            <Polyline x:Name="Poly1" Stroke="Red"/>
            <Polyline x:Name="Poly2" Stroke="Orange"/>
        </Canvas>
```

Comment: Where is the code that draws the polyline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The challenge is that i want to draw it "slowly", with a selectable delay before the next point gets added.

I think you could add the [task delay](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay?view=net-6.0) before `Points.Add` method. For example

```
for (int i = 0; i < P1points.Count; i++)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Poly1.Points.Add(P1points[i]);
}
```

Comment: i actually tried that, but i didn't thought of using the await operator... anyway, thanks a lot!